# После выбора элемента не закрывать диалог spinner

Tags: android

Всем привет! Кто знает как сделать так чтобы диалог Spinnera после выбора элемента не закрывался.

Answer (score 1):

Единственное решение, которое мне удалось найти - это использовать `SherlockActionBar` с его 
внутренним классом `IcsSpinner` к которому есть исходники и где легко можно отключить `dismiss()` для диалога.

Исследую андроидовский родной `Spinner`. Я так и не понял зачем было так жестко прятать эту возможность. Возможно сегодня за ночь найду этому достойное объяснение))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как это прикрутить к spinner? Я спрашиваю потому что в spinner есть обработчик onClick, но не параметров DialogInterface dialog, int which. Только View v.

Comment: ну так и создайте наследника от Spinner, а у него перегрузите этот метод.
и его используйте повсеместно где это необходимо.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ.

Comment: Извините вру)) я попытался написать сам что-то подобное и столкнулся с проблемами. надеюсь сейчас смогу решить Вашу проблемму и дать более детальный ответ.

и уберите пожалуйства метку с моего ответа. он не верен

Comment: хорошо)Я вас понял.